# Нужно ли присваивать значение при формировании пакета?

Tags: winsock, c++

Формируется пакет, и есть пустые значения, которые не нужны, но принимающая сторона требует их, и она получает нужные данные, делая сдвиг по размеру их типа (то есть ей просто нужно, чтобы 4 байта, допустим, были, а что в них - неважно). Так вот, если в пакет записать пустую  unsigned int переменную, то не сдвинутся ли соседние байты на её место?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет.